# Dihedral group as a semidirect product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups, semidirect-product

It is known that the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is isomorphic to the semidirect product  $Z_n\rtimes Z_2$, where both $Z_n,Z_2$ are cyclic.

My question is, for a semidirect prouct, the two subgroups should have trivial intersection. But, if $n$ be even, then how can we get trivial intersection? Namely, an order $2$ element  would be common to both $Z_n,Z_2$ right? And the order two elements in a dihedral group would be either a $180$ degree rotation about an axis or a reflection about an axis, which are both identical right? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: The order-$2$-element of $Z_n$ can be another than that used in $Z_2$

Comment: A group can have more than one element of order $2$.

Comment: @ElliotG I agree, but in a dihedral group, both reflection about an axis and $180$ degree rotation about the same axis are identical right?

Comment: I see your question now, but no. Consider a clock being rotated 180 degrees versus reflected about a vertical line.

Comment: @ElliotG ok, so the different axes of operation (rotation or reflection) give rise to different elements right?

Comment: To avoid confusion about this in fact we construct the semidirect product by considering the set of cartesian product of the two groups and then defining a new product.

Comment: I foind the following argument to be sometimes useful in this context. Consider a regular polygon painted black on one side, and white on the other. Lay it down with the black face up. Rotate it by $\pi$. The black face is still up. Now reflect it around an axis. Now it is the white face to be up.

Comment: @vidyarthi you claim that a reflection about an axis and "a 180 degree rotation about the same axis" are "identical", but this mixes up two different contexts: if you have a line L in $\mathbb R^2$ viewed as the x-y plane in $\mathbb R^3$, then the rotation of $\mathbb R^3$ about L by $180$ degrees acts on the x-y plane just as the reflection in the plane across the line L does. The rotations in the dihedral group, however, correspond to rotations about the z-axis if you wish to view them as symmetries of $\mathbb R^3$, not about an axis lying in the x-y plane.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same confusion. I used to mistake inner for external semidirect product. When we write $C_{n}\rtimes C_{2}$, we just construct a new binary operation on the cartesian product $C_{n}\times C_{2}$. So $C_{2}\le C_{n}$ (if exists), has nothing to do with $C_{2}$ that acts on $C_{n}$. On the other hand, when we say $G$ is inner semidirect of its two subgroups, we mean that there exists a normal subgroup $N\le G$, and a subgroup $K$ (not necessarily normal), where $G=NK$ and $N\cap K=1$. In this case you can prove that $G=NK\cong N\rtimes K$.

For more detailed explanations, please check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map
\begin{align*}
  \phi\colon\mathbb Z_2&\to\text{Aut}(\mathbb Z_n)\\
  t&\mapsto(c\mapsto(-2t+1)c).
\end{align*}
It is easy to verify that $\phi(t_1+t_2)=\phi(t_1)\circ\phi(t_2)$, i.e., that $\phi$ is an homomorphism. Then we can define the associated action
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_n&\to\mathbb Z_n\\
  (t,c)&\mapsto t\cdot c=(-2t+1)c.
\end{align*}
The multiplication in $\mathbb Z_n\rtimes\mathbb Z_2$ is then
$$
  (c_1,t_1)(c_2,t_2) = (c_1+(-2t_1+1)c_2, t_1+t_2),
$$
where the factor $-2t_1+1$ expresses the difference with the sum operation in $\mathbb Z_n$ (source of your confusion). Note however, that $(0,0)$ is still the identity. In particular,
$$
  (0,t)^2 = (0,0)
$$
and so $(0,1)$ is an involution and
\begin{align*}
  (c,0)^{(0,1)} &= (0,1)(c,0)(0,1)\\
                &= ((-2+1)c,1)(0,1)\\
                &= (-c,0)\\
                &= (c,0)^{-1}
\end{align*}
because $(c,0)(-c,0)=(c-c,0)=(0,0)$.

The other involutions are
$$
  (c,0)(0,1) = (c,1),
$$
which exactly correspond to the elements of $\mathbb Z_n\rtimes\mathbb Z_2\setminus D$, where $D$ is the image of $\mathbb Z_n$ in $\mathbb Z_n\rtimes\mathbb Z_2$.

Finally, note that the intersection of $\mathbb Z_n$ with $\mathbb Z_2$ inside $\mathbb Z_n\rtimes\mathbb Z_2$ is trivial because $\mathbb Z_n$ is embedded as $\{(c,0)\mid c\in\mathbb Z_n\}$ and $\mathbb Z_2$ as $\{(0,t)\mid t\in\mathbb Z_2\}$.